# Same dynamic route for mutltiple different pages - next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an endpoint in the /api folder for fetching what we call `assets`. I wanted to implement search so I created a folder called `assets` with an `index.js` and a `[query].js`.

And this works fine but now I also need to implement a detailed page for a single assets with an endpoint `assets/id`. Since I already have the query handler if I creating `[id].js` will lead to conflicts.

What's the ideal way of dealing with this?

Comment: How do you know if a user wants to access [query] or [id]? Write that logic in a single file [foo] that works like: if request is query then processQuery() else processId(). You can store those functions outside the pages directory.